# How to compare/match values in sql server in two different tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I need to have two tables.

First table (`tblStudent`) has fields  `student_id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`class`,`rollno`.

Second table(`feeType`) has fields `class`,`admissionFee`, `tuitionFee` etc.

I want to show the different fee for each class. 
Like class 5 pays 600 as tuition fee where as class 6 will pay 700.

Eg. If class is 5 in first table then only the class 5 row in `feeType` should be shown ? How do I design tables as such? How do I join two tables? I will be using sql server 2008 and c# as frontend. Thanks from a novice.

Comment: Sounds as you need to open some book first

Comment: @T.S. I certainly do sir. Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest type of INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStudent AS s
INNER JOIN feeType as f ON s.class = f.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your INNER JOIN would only return matching records,for non-matching records you could use a FULL JOIN and WHERE criteria to check.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblStudent AS s
INNER JOIN feeType as f ON s.class = f.class where s.class=null;
```

[Visit here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks you for helping out. I will soak it in all.

Comment: What do you mean by non-matching records here can you give example?

Comment: 'where s.class=null' returns non matching records

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the class names and their fees.

```
SELECT 
     s.class, 
     f.admissionFee as admission_fee, 
     f.tuitionFee as tuition_fee
FROM 
     tblStudent as s
     JOIN feeType as f ON s.class = f.class
GROUP BY 
     s.class;
```

I hope this will help you to get the exact result set.

Comment: Your code gave me error "'feeType.admissionFee' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." so I added these "     f.admissionFee,
     f.tutionFee;" in group by clause only then the code worked.